# Variable in Angular service

Tags: angularjs

In my service I have :

```
angular.module('Name.Common', [])

.service('myData', function($http) {
  $http.get('server.com/json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        this.companies = data;
        var companies2 = data;

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });


    this.getCompanies = function() {
        return this.companies; //?? return companies2; // ?

    };

});
```

Basically, I just want to get a json file from an http request and return it in the fonction getCompanies, Which the propoer way to do this ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service you only need to return the request:

```
angular.module('Name.Common', [])

.service('myData', function($http) {
    var self = this;

    self.get = function(){
        return $http.get('server.com/json');
    }
});
```

Then in your controller you handle the ".then" for the data:

```
var companies;

myData.get()
    .then(function (response) {
        companies = response; //data only available after this is hit
        console.log(companies); 
    });
```

Comment: Great it is working! But outside my controller, console.log(this.companies) prints undefined, any ideas ?

Comment: This should work, can you update your controller code in the question ?

Comment: I almost used the same code as K. Burrell, except that I added console.log(this.companies) after myData.get() method, and it prints undefined

Comment: Hmm thats because of angular promises (comically explained here http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html). Your console.log outside of myData.get() doesn't wait for the data to be returned to execute. In short you can only user the results of a http call inside a then / catch function or you can pass the response to another function after you get the results.

Comment: @Doapper I've changed my answer to try and help a little. If you want to log it, you should log it inside the '.then' because the data wont be available until it is fetched and set.

Comment: My problem is solved, but now I have another problem as M22an said, I think it is better to open a new question. Thank you very much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123466/angular-controller-with-http-get-request if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem I see here. you do the http call and in the callback you set `this`, but that isn't the `this` of the service. The same with the `var` it is locally bound. So the outside service function has no idea of it. 
What I would suggest is something like that. I havn't tested it, but it should work

```
angular.module('Name.Common', [])
  .service('myData', function($http) {
     var _this = this;
     var companies;

     $http.get('server.com/json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    _this.companies = data;
    companies = data;

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });


    this.getCompanies = function() {
      return _this.companies; // that part I would test if it works with just this.
      // or return companies2
   };
});
```

Comment: Thanks but when I do console.log(_this.companies); I have undefined. (and atter the http get, the console.log(data) is working)

Comment: where do you do the console.log(), to be clear. something like that wouldn't  work `this.a; $http.get().then(data => this.a = data); console.log(a)`

Comment: I have done the console.log(_this.companies) in the beginning of the getCompanies function