# Assign value to controller variable asyncronously - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

I get data from remote request by `companiesData.getCompanies()` and put it into controller variable.

The controller does not wait for promise resolution, figuring the response array empty.

**JS controller :**

```
angular.module('X.Exh', [])

.controller('ExhibitorsController', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, companiesData) {

    this.companies = [];

    companiesData.getCompanies().then(function(response) {
        this.companies = response.data;
console.log(this.companies); // working very well
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
 <ion-alpha-scroll ng-model="Exh.companies" key="name" display-key="name" subheader="true" use-complete-alphabet="true">
<!-- Basically the ion alpha scroll is just doing a ng-repeat for every item, it is not the problem here -->
```

Not waiting for the HTTP request, `Exh.companies` figures empty. (of course if I don't do `this.companies = [];` at the beginning of my controller, my HTML says that `Exh.companies` is undefined.

How do I get data properly?

Comment: Use $scope.componies = [];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this inside the unnamed function does not influence original `this.companies`:

```
angular
 .module('X.Exh', [])
 .controller('ExhibitorsController', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, companiesData) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.companies = []; // you can omit this but for documentation and code clear you can declare it;

    companiesData.getCompanies().then(function(response) {
        vm.companies = response.data;
        console.log(vm.companies); // does not point to local this.companies but to the caller context.
    });
});
```

Please **note** that `vm.` runs when you use `controllerAs` [pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example).

Alternatively you can simply access `$scope` variable:

```
angular
 .module('X.Exh', [])
 .controller('ExhibitorsController', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, companiesData) {

    $scope.companies = []; // you can omit this but for documentation and code clear you can declare it;

    companiesData.getCompanies().then(function(response) {
        $scope.companies = response.data;
        console.log($scope.companies); // does not point to local this.companies but to the caller context.
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right! but actually I used var self = this; and then self.companies. It is a good solution?

Comment: `var self = this;` is the same as `var vm = this;` so the only constraint is to declare `ng-controller='ExhibitorsController as Exh'` and access data in the html like `Exh.myvar`. You are already achieving this second solution that is also a best practice for large application, so its'ok.